# Is there a way to $_POST using "id" rather than "name"

Tags: html, post

I want to output details posted from a form using the $_POST method. I have all the details outputted from the form except for one which is $_POST['randomStrings']; Now the reason for this which I believe is that all the other details recieve details from the form using the "name" method, while randomStrings is an "id", not a "name". Now I tried changing it to a name but if I do that then what it is suppose to perform in the form would not work, so what my question is that is there to be able to use $_POST to post a form  variable by "id" rather than "name"?

Below is code (showing only relevant code, not all code):

```
 <p>id="randomStrings"></p>

<p>Session Id: {$_POST['randomStrings']}</p>
```

Comment: No. (Un)fortunately not.

Comment: An element can have both an ID and a Name. You don't need to "change it to a name", you can just add the name and keep the ID.

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't recognise "randomStrings"

Answer (score 2):

You should read up the HTML specification, it will answer your question.

You can use `name` and `id` as attributes like so:

```
<input type="test" id="randomString" name="randomString" />
```

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work, I said I changed it to name but what I meant to say was add it as a name. Also it is not an input, it is just something to display a text

Comment: Can you post precisely what you've tried to do?  I get the impression you've tried to do this to a `<p>` element, which is not a form control so will not submit anything.

Comment: Well I tried doing your way by including <input> which doesn't affect what it performs on the form which is generate random strings but still not recognsing index

Comment: 1. Where are the random strings coming from (javascript?)? 2. Again, can you please post precisely what you have tried so that we can look for bugs in it.

Answer (score 2):

The way you would do this is to create a form input that is hidden and put your info in there.

E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="randomStrings" value="<put value in here>" />
```

This will POST the value into $_POST['randomStrings']

Answer (score 1):

If you're attaching the ID and Name element to a `<p>` tag, it won't get submitted.

`p` is not a form element.

You could put the content of `p` in a hidden element and then it will get submitted.

```
<p id="randomString">
    Some Text
    <input type="hidden" value="Some Text" name="randomString" />
</p>
```